# Class member in java and assignment

Tags: java, class

Below is my program which i have doubts about:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    class degrees
    {
    float faren;
    //float cel = (faren-32)*0.55f; doesn work
    void conversion()
    {
        System.out.println("Fahrenheit is "+(faren-32)*0.55f+"Celcius");
        //System.out.println("Fahrenheit is "+cel+"Celcius"); doesnt work
    }
    }

    class Problem4 
    {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        degrees deg = new degrees();
        System.out.println("Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit");
        try(Scanner n1 = new Scanner(System.in))
        {
            deg.faren = n1.nextFloat();
        }
        deg.conversion();
    }
   }
```

So the two statements that i have made comments

```
  float cel = (faren-32)*0.55f;// this one and 
  System.out.println("Fahrenheit is "+cel+"Celcius");//this one
```

Both the above statement does not work. I m assigning the value of faren by calling object but still. Can anybody explain me why?

Its just a simple program so please don't correct the mistakes if any. I need to figure out myself. Just help me with the above two statement guys.

Comment: Do you get any error? can you post up your stack trace please?

Comment: @KickButtowski I didnt get any error with those two statement included. And i how do i get stack trace in eclipse, i have netbeans too.

Comment: this `float cel = (faren-32)*0.55f;` does not work because you cannot initialise a property when defined with an expression. this `System.out.println("Fahrenheit is "+cel+"Celcius");` does not work similarly because `cel` has not been defined/converted (by 1st reason). Initialise the values in the constructor instead

Comment: What you mean by "does not work"? Are you getting errors or an invalid output?

Comment: @MickMnemonic yes invalid output, the second print statement always indicates -17.6

Comment: @NikosM. So if i use float cel = (faren-32)*0.55f; in main, only then it will work, but here since i m referring to cel using object, i must initialize the local variable first as a thumb rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this instead:

```
class degrees
    {
    float faren = 0;
    float cel = 0;

    void degrees(float faren)
    {
       this.faren = faren;
       this.cel = (this.faren-32)*5.0f/9.0f;
    }
    void conversion()
    {
        //System.out.println("Fahrenheit is "+(this.faren-32)*0.55f+"Celcius");
        System.out.println("Fahrenheit is "+this.cel+"Celcius");
    }
    }
```

use like this:

```
var deg = new degrees(farheneitValueHere);
deg.conversion();
```

this `float cel = (faren-32)*0.55f;` does not work because you cannot initialise a property when defined with an expression (especially an expression which includes another property). this `System.out.println("Fahrenheit is "+cel+"Celcius");` does not work similarly because `cel` has not been defined/converted (by 1st reason). Initialise the values in the constructor instead (as in the example above)

Comment: Yes i was going to post a question about "this" keyword too but i guess now you have cleared it to me with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are attempting to convert `faren` from Fahrenheit to Celsius before `faren` is given a value.  Java will initialize class variables to `0` if not given a value, so `cel` will be given the Celsius equivalent of 0 Fahrenheit.  The reason you get `-17.6` is that's the result of `(0 - 32) * 0.55f`.

Instead of using class variables, have your `conversion` method take a parameter in degrees Fahrenheit, do the math in the method, and then return the Celsius value.

Also, `conversion` isn't very descriptive of the purpose.  You may want to rename the method `fahrenheitToCelsius` or something similar.

For accuracy you should to multiply by `5.0f/9.0f` instead of `0.55f`.

Comment: got it that way i can intitalize the class memeber in beginning as 0 and after passing the value through argument in method, i can calculate it and return it like "return (fahren - 32) * 5/9;"